# string tokenizer function error segmented core

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a tokenizer for a dynamic string input but I'm getting the error "segmented fault(core dump)' when I try to run it.Here's the code for the function and an execution example

```
#include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int main()
  {int num_words = 0;
  char **words = NULL;
  char **tokenize_string(char *str,int num_words)
  {
    num_words = 0;  
       // reinitialize -> 0 for each read
    char **words = NULL; // words array of strings that will be returned

    char *word = strtok(str, " ");
    while (word != NULL)
    {
      words = (char **)realloc(words, sizeof(char *) * (num_words + 1)); // dynamically reallocate the array of strings for each iteration : size of pointer to character (string) * number of words tokenized
      words[num_words] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(word) + 1));
      // allocate size of tokenized string
      strcpy(words[num_words], word);
      num_words++;
      word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    // Append a null character at the end of the array
    words = (char **)realloc(words, sizeof(char *) * (num_words + 1));
    words[num_words] = NULL;
    
    return words;
  }
  words = tokenize_string("ls wc tr qx",num_words);
  printf("%d",num_words);
  }
```

Comment: Functions do not nest in C..

Comment: Check the return values of ```realloc``` and ```malloc```, and ```free``` the memory you allocated through them.

Comment: Do not cast the result of ```malloc``` and family.

Comment: Aside: ```NULL``` is not a character.

Comment: @Haris size of the point

Comment: `strtok` modifies the string, and you're passing it a string literal. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior. Try `char myStr[] = "ls wc tr qx"; words = tokenize_string(myStr ,num_words);`, but there could be other problems. You should run your code in a debugger, it will most likely tell you where it's crashing.